# Parse, replacing large (several thousands) number of records

Tags: parse-platform

I've got a class in parse with 1-4k records per user. This needs to be replaced from time to time (actually these are records representing multiple timetables).

The problem I'm facing that deleting and inserting these records is a ton of requests. Is there maybe a method to delete and insert a bunch of records, that counts as one request? Maybe it's possible from Cloud Code?

I tried compacting all this data in one record, but then I faced the size limit for records (128 KB). Using any sub format(like a db or file onside a record) would be really tedious, cause the app is targeting nearly all platforms supported by Parse.

**EDIT**

For clarification, the problem isn't the limit on saveAll/destroyAll. My problem is facing the req/s limit (or rather, as docs state req/min).
Also, I just checked that requests from Cloud Code also seem to count towards that limit.

Well, a possible solution would be also to redesing my datasets and use Array columns or something, but I'd rather avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this isn't an *answer* to my question, but it's a *solution* to my problem, so I'm posting it.

My problem was storing and then replacing a large amount of small records which add up to significant size (up to 500KB JSON [~1.5MB XML] in my current plans).
So I've chosen a middle path - I implemented sort of vertical partitions.

What I have is a master User record which holds array of pointers to other class (called Entries). Entries have only 2 fields - ID of school record and data which is type Array.

I decided to split "partitions" every 1000 records, which is about ~60-70KB per record, but in my calculations may go up to ~100KB.
I also made field names in json 1 letter, cause every letter in 1000 records is like 1 or 2 KB, depending on encoding.

Actually that approach made PHP code like twice as fast and there is a lot less usage on network and remote database (1000 times less inserts/destroys basically).

So, that is my solution, if anybody has any other ideas, please post it as answer here, cause probably I'm not the only one with such problem and that certainly isn't the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try Parse.Object.saveAll which batch processes the save() function.

Docs: https://www.parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Object.html#.saveAll

Guide: https://parse.com/questions/parseobjectsaveall-performances

Comment: Currently I'm using that approach (And destroyAll) but from PHP, the problem is the amount of requests (that count towards the limit) and the script errors with exception saying that limit was exceeded, try again in one minute. Or maybe coud code's requests don't count towards the limit? Haven't tried that, yet

Comment: How many objects did you add to saveAll operation? I think the limit could be 1000 objects since there's no mention in docs.

Comment: Well, the docs for the API state that one batch request can have max 50 requests (the library splits them, I've checked) and that they all count towards the req/s limit. I've added ~2k objects. And they all get deleted, then the script generates new data and tries to insert ~2k objects and then Parse is like 'no, no, you've exceeded you're req/s limit'

Comment: I see your point now. Have you tried parse's PHP SDK? They have saveAll method too. http://parseplatform.github.io/parse-php-sdk/classes/Parse.ParseObject.html#method_saveAll. Maybe the problem is related to req/s, but we can give it a try if they actually bypass it with their official SDKs.

Comment: I'm using they're official API, but it's just a wrapper for REST API, so no use there. I also tried it from Cloud Code, but it's still counting towards the limit. What saveAll does is go through all objects in chain and flaten it, if there is a cycle then error. Then create REST requests and batch them if there is more than one. I didn't try the Master Key though, but I would assume that the same limit applies.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a saveAll/DestroyAll (or DeleteAll?) and anything -All that parse provides in its SDK.

You'd still reach a 1000 objects `limit`, but to counter that you can loop using the `.skip` property of a request.

Set a `limit` of 1000 and `skip` of 0, do the query, then increase the `skip` value by the previous `limit`, and so on. And you'd have 2 or 3 requests of a size of 1000 each time. You stop the loop when your `results count` is smaller than your `limit`. If it's not, then you query again and set the `skip` to the `limit x loopcount`.

Now you say you're facing size issues, maybe you can reduce that query `limit` to, say, 400, and your loop would just run for longer until your number of results is smaller than your `limit` (and then you can stop querying/limiting/skipping/looping or anything in -ing).

Comment: My problem isn't the limits on saveAll/destroyAll themselves (there are none), I've added clarification to question.

Comment: Yeah exactly, but saveAll should only be _1_ request, or are you sayign that when you call that you have 1000 reuqests?

Comment: Yeah, it is one REST request, the thing is, that according to [Parse REST API docs](https://parse.com/docs/rest#objects-batch) _Note that N requests sent in a batch will still count toward your request limit as N requests._